# How to evaluate operations then print a message

Tags: c++

Take 4 variables from user w, x ,y ,z.
If w ‘x’ y = z print “You are right” otherwise, print
“ERROR

Below is the code I created for this problem, but it seems there is something wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void calculate(int w, char x, int y, int z)
{
    if (x == '+') {
        int z = w + y ;
        cout << "You are right" <<endl;
    }
    else if (x == '-') {
        int z = w - y ;
        cout << "You are right" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == '*') {
        int z = x * y;
        cout << "You are right" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int w, y, z;
    char x;
    cout << "Enter values for w, x, y, and z: " << endl;
    cin >> w >> x >> y >> z;
    cout << endl;
    calculate(w, y, x, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you check that `w 'x' y` actually does equal `z`? It looks like you just immediately say "you are right" no matter what `z` is.

Comment: Flagging this as typo. `int z = w + y ;` should be `if (z == w + y)`, same for others. Moreover, `if-else` ladder is corrupted. Last `else` block needs to be moved inside each of the cases, or better store the answer in another integer and then compare it with `z` at last. You should first go and read a good C++ book. Another typo is `calculate(w, y, x, z);`. It should be `calculate(w, x, y, z);` instead! [Fixed Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NGAbpReK6gJlyQwc)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
void calculate(int w, char x, int y, int z)
{
    if (x == '+') {
        int z = w + y ;
        cout << "You are right" <<endl;
    }
    else if (x == '-') {
        int z = w - y ;
        cout << "You are right" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == '*') {
        int z = x * y;
        cout << "You are right" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
}
```

If you look closely `int z = w + y` is wrong as you are already taking `z` as a function parameter.
The correct statement, however, would be `z  = w + y`.

The second thing, you need to remove `int z` from your function parameters, but declare and define it inside the function body. This is because when you pass `z` from `main()`, you aren't really passing the variable `z`. But merely the value of it which will get copied into `int z` in `calculate`.

## Passing `z` as a reference

If you want the `z` in your main to update, you shall pass the value by reference.

```cpp
void calculate(int w,char x,int y,int& z)
{
    //updating z
}
```

Now, if you apply any change to `z` in `calculate()`, it will also appear your `main()`.

Another solution is to to return `int` from the function and assign to the variable `z` in `main()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int calculate(int w,int y,char x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case '+': 
            std::cout << "You are right!\n";
            return w+y;
        case '-':
            std::cout << "You are right!\n";
            return w-y;
        case '*':
            std::cout << "You are right!\n";
            return w*y;
            
        default:
            std::cout << "You are wrong!\n";
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int w = 5;
    int y = 10;
    char x = '+';
    int z = calculate(w,y,x);
    std::cout << z;

    return 0;
}
```